# How to search and filter issues on created field by specific date JIRA search API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

i am using following URL with post request
https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/2/search

request body

```
{
    "jql": "project = AF AND created='2022/09/06'",
    "startAt": 1,
    "maxResults": 15,
    "fields": [
        "summary",
        "status",
        "assignee",
        "project",
        "created",
        "priority",
        "duedate",
        "description",
        "issuetype"
    ]
}
```

i have two issues created at date '2022/09/06'. but it is giving no result

```
{
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 15,
    "total": 0,
    "issues": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Equal operator may not work because of the hidden "hours" inside the date in your JQL.

You may try something following:

```
project = AF AND created >= '2022/09/06' AND created < '2022/09/07'
```

Also, you can use some other advanced JQL operations inside that boundaries:

1. You can use `created > "-1d"` for the issues created last day. (If the number is 10, it means created last 10 days)
2. You can use `created >= startOfDay(-1d)` for the issues created since yesterday.

Atlassian's [Advanced JQL Guide](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-work-management/docs/advanced-search-reference-jql-operators/) may help you for further information.

Comment: Happy to hear that; please also accept the answer if everything's ok :)